Unable to make request after upgrading to Microsoft Graph Java SDK V6 from V5
I am trying to upgrade to MSGraph SDK from v5 to v6 following this guide. I have made the necessary changes so far, and the application can start. However, I am encountering an error while making a test call.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext.setCaeEnabled(boolean)'
at com.microsoft.kiota.authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider.getAuthorizationToken(AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider.java:161) ~[microsoft-kiota-authentication-azure-1.7.0.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.kiota.authentication.BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider.authenticateRequest(BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider.java:46) ~[microsoft-kiota-abstractions-1.7.0.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.getHttpResponseMessage(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:710) ~[microsoft-kiota-http-okHttp-1.7.0.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.send(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:275) ~[microsoft-kiota-http-okHttp-1.7.0.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.graph.users.item.UserItemRequestBuilder.get(UserItemRequestBuilder.java:761) ~[microsoft-graph-6.20.0.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.graph.users.item.UserItemRequestBuilder.get(UserItemRequestBuilder.java:747) ~[microsoft-graph-6.20.0.jar:na]

Does that mean I am having the problem with the authentication?
Notice: the same credentials(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId) were used for V5.
This is my authentication after the migration:
@Configuration
public class GraphConfiguration {
    private static final String SCOPE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

    @Bean
    public GraphServiceClient graphClient(AadAuthenticationProperties aadAuthenticationProperties) throws Exception {
        ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(aadAuthenticationProperties.getCredential().getClientId())
                .clientSecret(aadAuthenticationProperties.getCredential().getClientSecret())
                .tenantId(aadAuthenticationProperties.getProfile().getTenantId())
                .build();

        if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected error while initializing GraphServiceClient");
        }

        return new GraphServiceClient(credential, SCOPE);
    }
}

and this is the call:
public void getLoggedInUserInfo() {
   var users = graphServiceClient
          .users()
          .get(); // this is where the error comes from
}


I also tried to override the default kiota version with the latest version 1.8.x but it also did not help.

You are using client secret and authenticating without the signed-in user, so you can't call graphServiceClient.me().get().

@user2250152 you are right. That was a bad test call. I have edited my test call. But the issue is still there if I call users().get(). This call should not require signed-in user.
